# jackson xmlmapper dynamic attribute names

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I want to generate following xml:

```
 <word start="1556" end="1564" TestArticle="36" Chemical="7">Ammonium</word> 
 <word start="1566" end="1584" Endpoint="36" Chemical="7" >per-fluorobutyrate</word> 
 <word start="1585" end="1586" TestArticle="37" >(</word>
```

I am using following pojo, which takes care of start and end as they are fixed attribute names, but I have "testArticle", "Endpoint", "Chemcial", etc which are dynamic in nature as well as there value, which I am not sure how to handle.

```
public class WordPOJO {

@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
String start;
@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
String end;
@JacksonXmlText
String str;

// not sure if this is the way to do it, but it not outputing in desired format
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
List<String> entityList;


public String getStart() {
    return start;
}
public void setStart(String span) {
    this.start = span;
}

public String getEnd() {
    return end;
}
public void setEnd(String span) {
    this.end = span;
}

public List<String> getEntityList()
{
    return entityList;
}

public void setEntityList(List<String> entityList)
{
    this.entityList = entityList;
}
 
//@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
//@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "word")
public String getStr() {
    return str;
}
public void setStr(String str) {
    this.str = str;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the XML attribute names `TestArticle` , `Chemical` and `Endpoint` in adavance,
then you can represent these as additional properties in your `WordPOJO` Java class:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "TestArticle")
String testArticle;

@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "Chemical")
String chemical;

@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "Endpoint")
String endpoint;

// Getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
```

Notice that you also need to explicitly specify the XML names
by `localName = "..."`) to match your XML content.
(See also the [javadoc of `@JacksonXmlProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlProperty.html).)
If you would not do this, then Jackson would implicitly
pick up XML names derived from your Java property names
(`testArticle`, `chemical`, `endpoint`) which would not match
your actual XML content.

---

If the XML attributes are truly dynamic and you don't know them in advance,
then you will need to use `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter`.
See the [javadoc of @JsonAnyGetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html) and [JsonAnySetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html).

Don't be irritated by `Json` in the annotation names. Jackson can handle JSON and XML and many more formats. For JSON you use [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html).
And for XML you use [`XmlMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper.html).

```
Map<String, Object> otherProperties = new HashMap<>();

@JsonAnySetter
public void setOtherProperty(String name, String value) {
    otherProperties.put(name, value);
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object>  getOtherProperties() {
    return otherProperties;
}
```

Comment: I am going to have lot more such attributes which would be generated on fly, I wont know before hand, so I can explicity add these to POJO. I am looking for adding them dynamically.

Comment: @user1631306 Ah I see, I missed that part in your question. See the amendment in my answer.

Comment: isnt it for Json format? is there similar thing for XML?

Comment: @user1631306 The `Json` in the annotation names originates from historical reasons. See my amendment. again.

Comment: thanks for clarification. I tried and now i get the following :  <word start="25" end="27">of<yellow>3</yellow><hello>1</hello></word>, instead of  <word start="25" end="27" yellow = "3" hello = "1"> of</word>

Comment: @user1631306 May be adding `@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)` will fix this issue.

Comment: @user1631306 See this Jackson issue: [XML Serialization + JsonAnyGetter as attributes](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/309)

Comment: Thanks, I checked the link and used the porposed solution. All is good except, now i dont have the text value in the xml, as in "Ammonium" is missing now